# Android: storing an unchanging reference to images in a database

Tags: android, sqlite, drawable

fellow programmers! I'm new... hope you can help!

So. I'm currently developing an application that allows users to choose four different images from a set of images that I have saved in my res/drawable/ folder, and then save those choices as an entry in a database.However, I then need to be able to redisplay those four images when the user asks for them, and I'm not sure what the best way of storing the images is since my current setup isn't going to work for me in the future.

Right now, I have it working so that I actually insert the R.java int identifiers into the database for each of the images, so the database has four columns: img1(int), img2(int), img3 (int), img4 (int). Then when I write a query, I just use those values in place of R.drawable.someImage.

It works fine. Except... when I add new images to my res/drawable folder, all of the drawable ids get changed! Then the ids I have in the database are wrong, and some pull up the wrong images, and some throw NullPointerExceptions!

This is a problem, because I want to be able to update the app with new images after the users download it. How should I be storing these images so that they can be dynamically chosen, but then be reliably be referenced again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources can be accessed as raw data: use [AssetManager.open(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String%29) Then you can use [BitmapFactory.decodeStream(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) to create a Bitmap from the data stream.

So you can just save filenames of images and instantiate Bitmaps via above commands.

Comment: Can you elaborate just a little bit on what AssetManagers do? I looked at the API, of course, but somehow it takes me a lot longer than other programmers to understand that stuff. Basically, are you saying that I don't even need identifiers if I store the images as raw data, and use the AssetManager to access that data? Thanks for your help!

Comment: AssetManager: Provides access to an application's raw asset files. So you can open any resource/asset file (bitmaps, XML) as raw data stream. In practice this is only useful for images, like in your case.

Comment: You don't have to store images in any particular way - just leave them as they are (*.png files). Just give AssetManager their name (i.e. "drawable/image.png") and it'll return a data stream. It's just like opening a file and reading data from it.

Comment: Guess I know what I've got to muck around with today... thanks! You guys have been great.

Answer (score 1):

> This is a problem, because I want to be able to update the app with new images after the users download it.

I don't quite understand this - if you are going to distribute new images 'after' the users download your app then the new images are never going to have resource ids (as found in R.java) as these are auto-generated as part of the build process.

Do you really mean this or do you intend to update the app with new images and have the users download it again?

If you are going to update the app with new images periodically and have the users download the updated app, you can find the resource id at runtime using...

```
int resId = getResources.getIdentifier("img1", "drawable", "com.mycompany.mypackagename");
```

At this point, of course, you'll need to know the names of all the drawables although this could be achieved with a string array in your res/values/strings.xml.

If, however, you want to add new images without the need for the user updating the app, I'd think about maintaining an image directory (on the SD card for example). This way, you would simply just need to store the path to the image files in the DB.

Comment: Hmmm... I do mean that I'm going to periodically provide new image "packs", so I suppose it's going to have to be in the form of an update. Isn't that how apps are updated anyway? A new version is just downloaded? If not, please let me know... that's another area of Android that's a bit shady to me right now.

Oh, and also, I have tried the getIdentifier function, and that works as well, but I've heard it's inefficient to access the resources that way. Guess it's my only option though. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Haley: What I meant about making new images available without updating the app is if, for example, you provide image downloads from your website, i.e., the app may periodically check your website and notify the user of new images which they can choose to download. In this case they'd be 'external' to the app unlike 'internal' images like those in res/drawable. If you're going to have them all as 'internal' then Peter Knego's answer may be better than using getIdentifier (from a code point of view) although I doubt it's more efficient. :-)

Comment: Hey, thanks! My app isn't very resource intensive, so I probably don't need to worry too much about efficiency at this stage. I'll probably just move the images to the raw directory and work with data streams... wish me luck!